# Rails: undefined method `renderer' for ApplicationController:Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to use

```
ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'details/proposal')
```

in Mailer

Any Help??

Comment: Are you using rails 5?

Answer (score 0):

The `ApplicationController.renderer.render` is new to Rails 5. If you aren't on 5, it unfortunately won't be available to you yet.

On Rails 4, the simplest way is to use [ActionView::Base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Base/new/class]), like this:

```
controller = ActionController::Base.new
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {}, controller)
view.render(partial: 'details/proposal')
```